# Improper array handling by jQuery: length= 0 bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I don't know if this is my little knowledge of jQuery or it is just a bug, but here's what happens. I have this small piece of JSON code

---

```
{
    "planes":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Boeing 767-300",
            "height":54.9 ,
            "wingspan":47.6, 
            "vel": 851,
            "vel max":913,
            "plane width":283.3,
            "weight":86070, 
            "full weight":158760, 
            "passengers":{
                "1 class":350,
                "2 class":269,
                "3 class":218
            },
            "fuel tank":90.625,
            "engine":"2 turbofan General Electric CF6-80C2"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Boeing 737-800",
            "height":33.4 ,
            "wingspan":35.8, 
            "vel": 840,
            "vel max":945,
            "plane width":105.44,
            "weight":32704, 
            "full weight":56472, 
            "passengers":{
                "1 class":189
            },
            "fuel tank":90.625,
            "engine":"2 turbofan CFM56-3C1"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

which I'm then getting with jQuery's `getJSON` without any flaw. Then I want two separate arrays: one holding the keys and the other holding the values, and again no problem with `Object.keys` and `Object.values`. By logging the result in a single string, everything is fine. Until I try to construct an associative array using keys as indexes and values as data. By logging the result, I get an extra "length" index with value "0". here's my jQuery code

---

```
var arr=[];
$.getJSON("js/jsondata.json", function(data){
    var keys= Object.keys(data.planes[0]);
    var values= Object.values(data.planes[0]);
//im only testing on the first object, for now

    $.each(keys, function(i){
//creating the associative index and assigning the value
        arr[keys[i]]= values[i];
        console.log("Key: "+ keys[i]+", Value: "+values[i]);
//this logs the exact values and indexes
    });
    console.log(arr);
//this logs an extra "length" 0
});
```

Comment: I think you need to change this `var arr=[];` to this `var arr={};` or to this `var arr=Object.create(null);`

Comment: You key is not an integer so are basically just recreating the object.... `var a = []; a['id] = 1; console.log(a.length)`

Answer (score 1):

What you really want to use is a `key-value` object and not an array.  So you have at least to options:

Actually the arrays are objects, and you will be able to attach/add new properties, however, this kind of objects have a pre-defined prototype and properties.  One of these properties is `length`.  Cause that, you're getting an "unexpected" property `length`.

1. Changing this `var arr = [];` to this `var arr = {};`.
2. Changing this `var arr = [];` to this `var arr = Object.create(null);`.

**Adding properties to an object array**

```js
let arr = [2];
arr['myKey'] = 'EleFromStack';

console.log(arr.myKey);
console.log(arr.length); // 1 cause length is part of Array type.
```

**Adding properties to a `key-value` object**

```js
let arr = {}; // Object.create(null);
arr['myKey'] = 'EleFromStack';

console.log(arr.myKey);
console.log(arr.length); // undefined cause length is not part of the Object type.
```

Answer (score 0):

Biggest problem is there's no such beast as associative arrays in JavaScript. All arrays must have numbered indices. Association the way you want is handled with objects.

So, you can just assign the first plane in your planes array to a variable and retain your original association rather than iterate it.

Is there a particular reason you're trying to disassemble and reassemble your object to an array this way?